# Changing content of footline in beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

How is it possible to set a specific text in the footline of the slides in beamer? In my case, author names and the title are shown. Instead I'd like to show the conference name and country.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\author{Elena Piper, Amina Shahid, April Fiorese}
\title{Evaluating the Change of Performance Metrics for Key ABS}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: The pack­age Times is ob­so­lete. Re­placed by the `math­ptmx` pack­age, which sup­ports Times Ro­man text and (mostly) match­ing math­e­mat­ics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\author`and `\title` can get options for the same usage that you have mentioned. In your case, since you have left the options blank, the title and the authors' names are inserted instead. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\author[conference title]{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
\title[My country]{Presentation title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]